# Remove Artifacts that were Deployed to Artifactory Repo with Maven

Tags: maven, artifactory

I deployed a certain jar file and pom to an artifactory repository using the following command format:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DpomFile= -Dfile= -DrepositoryId= -Durl=
```

The pom file I used was defective and is causing build issues for dependent projects. When I look at the corresponding area of the artifactory repo where the jar and pom were deployed, what I see is more than a simple tree with a pom file and jar.

Rather than manually picking through the repository to remove the defective pom I deployed and whatever errant directory structure it may have set up, is there a maven command I can execute that can "undo" what I committed in a clean fashion? thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Maven cannot "undeploy" files. You need to remove them inside the repository manager.